# how do i keep turtle.Screen() running AND take commands to move/ turn turtle?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-turtle

I am trying to basically make a copy version of LOGO but in my style (be easy on me).
So similar to LOGO (but not quite similar) i want to keep taking inputs in powershell and see the changes in the screen simultaneously.
BUT in this code the screen just opens and thats it, no prompt for input. Help me.
Here is the code:

```
#----------------
# turtle paint
#----------------

import turtle


def main():
    
    bg_color = input("What backgroud color would you like?")    # taking input for bg_color
    tur_color = input("What color of turtle will you like?")

    wn = turtle.Screen()        # creates a screen for turtle drawing
    wn.bgcolor(bg_color)
    tur = turtle.Turtle()           # tur is assigned Turtle
    
    move()

    print("Thank you for using Turtle paint.")

def move():
    wn.mainloop()
    print("Turtle is facing 'RIGHT'.")
    while True:
        
        try:                # to eliminate unnecessarily errors from popping up
            q = input("Turn or move forward?\nturn/forward> ")      # turn or move forward prompt
            
            # based on the answer take input of degree and forward movement length
            if q.lower() == "turn":
                turn = input("Turn 'Right' or 'Left'?")
                degree = int(input(f"Turn {turn} by how much degree"))
                if turn.lower() == 'right':
                    tur.right(degree)
                elif turn.lower() =='left':
                    tur.left(degree)
            
            elif q.lower() == 'forward':
                movement = int(input("How much forward? type in number\n> "))
                tur.forward(movement)
        
        except:
            print('Turtle didnt catch that, try again!')
        
        # if the user want to continue or not
        # there is semantic error probably
        print("Wanna continue?")
            ans = input('> ')       
            if ans in ['yes', 'Yes', "YES", 'Y' ,'y']:
                pass
            else:
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You can try to put the `input(...)` in another thread but I don't know if `turtle` is threadsafe.

Comment: i guess the issue will still remain. I didn't understand what is "another thread"?

Comment: First of all `wn.mainloop()` isn't going to end until the window is destroyed. So all of the code after it isn't executed. Second of all look at some basic tutorials on how threading works.

Comment: instead of input, try `turtle.textinput( title, message )` -- https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.textinput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
#----------------
# turtle paint
#----------------

import turtle
from threading import Thread


def main():
    global wn, tur

    wn = turtle.Screen()
    tur = turtle.Turtle()

    move()

def move_asker():
    print("Turtle is facing \"RIGHT\".")
    while True:
        try:
            q = input("Turn or move forward?\nturn/forward/exit> ")

            if q.lower() == "turn":
                turn = input("Turn right or left? ")
                degree = int(input(f"Turn {turn} by how much degree"))
                if turn.lower() == "right":
                    tur.right(degree)
                elif turn.lower() == "left":
                    tur.left(degree)

            elif q.lower() == "forward":
                movement = int(input("How much forward? type in number\n> "))
                tur.forward(movement)

            elif q.lower() == "exit":
                wn.destroy()
                break

        except RuntimeError:
            # The user might have closed the window
            break

        except Exception as error:
            print("Error = " + repr(error))
            print("Turtle didnt catch that, try again!")

def move():
    thread = Thread(target=move_asker, daemon=True)
    thread.start()
    wn.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In the `move` function, it tells python to start executing `move_asker()` and continue executing `wn.mainloop()`.

However there are problems with this approach. One of them is that `turtle` might crash without even giving you an error. That is why it isn't advisable to use `turtle` with threads. I tested all of the commands that are in the program right now and they should work.

It would be better if you switch from using `turtle` and use something like `tkinter` (`turtle` was built on top of `tkinter` so it shouldn't be that hard). If you do that, you use an `Entry` instead of using `input(...)`. It will solve the problem outlined above.

Comment: we are running the wn,mainloop() in completely different function and before running it we start the move_asker() function and then right after ask it to run mainloop(). thank you. I took on your advice and will be studying abt threading.